# Erro no binutils na hora de fazer Cross-compiler. lex: not found

Tags: c, c++, linux

Eu estou fazendo um cross-compiler para a arquitetura i686-elf com um host Debian 8 86_64 bits já desinstalei e instalei o flex mas o erro continua! Vou deixar o output do terminal.

```
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc -g -O2 ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc -g -O2 ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for flex... lex
checking for yywrap in -ll... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) gcc -E
checking lex output file root... ../../binutils-2.9/binutils/configure: 1701: ../../binutils-2.9/binutils/configure: lex: not found
configure: error: cannot find output from lex; giving up
Configure in /home/hikkarin/Documentos/GCC-4.9.0-CROSS/SRC/build-binutils/binutils failed, exiting.
```

Eu rodei isso com o comando:

linux32 ../binutils-2.9/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror

Comment: tanta instalar o pacote binutils 32bits

Comment: Já instalou o flex? `apt-get install flex`

Comment: Verifique se o flex está instalado, e se o lex é um link simbólico para o flex.